# Codeblock at the beginning of the personal statement formats incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

[image: Broken Example]

I don't really think this is a huge deal, since only people not in their right minds like myself would try starting a personal statement with code, but the preview *does* show the codeblock formatted:

[image: Broken Example]

Comment: Would you provide a link to your profile, if public? Or just let us know your OpenID by emailing careers@stackoverflow.com. We'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, it wasn't meant to be public, but I can put it up for inspection fpr a while.  http://careers.stackoverflow.com/mootinator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks! This should be resolved, please try it again.